# SpreadJs border not setting

Tags: javascript, spreadjs

I am trying to set a border using SpreadJs, however it is not working for me.

I have taken the example off their help documentation but it does not work, the border does not show up.

http://help.grapecity.com/spread/SpreadSheets11/webframe.html#SpreadJS~GC.Spread.Sheets.LineBorder.html

```
var border = new GC.Spread.Sheets.LineBorder;
border.color = "#7FFFD4";
border.style = GC.Spread.Sheets.LineStyle.medium;
var cell = sheet.getCell(5, 5, GC.Spread.Sheets.SheetArea.viewport);
cell.borderLeft(border);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that! I see the problem appears to be some missing parentheses in the constructor in that code snippet:

```
var border = new GC.Spread.Sheets.LineBorder();
```

That should solve the issue.

Regards,
GrapeCity Support